# SQL tables with boolean variables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am kind of new to SQL using  and i am playing with different scenarios.

My Example is as follows :

Suppose that i need to have a student enrollment system . I created the `student` table as follows :

```
create table student (net_id char(10) , first_name char(20)  ,
 last_name char(20) , Major char(10) , ISGraduate BOOLEAN,
                        primary key (net_id)
```

where `isgraduate` boolean variable measures whether a student is a graduate student or not.

I have a another entity which is `professor` as follows :

```
 create table professor (net_id char(10) , first_name char(20) 
 , last_name char(20) , Rank char(10) , department char(20) ,
                        primary key (net_id))
```

Then if i want to model the relationship : a professor can advise many graduate students , then i might need to create a new table `adviosry` , But in there how can i filter only the graduate students ?

any help would be great .

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure how the scenario makes sense, or if it needs to since you've stated you're just playing around right now; but you have two different spellings of "sugar". Also, I think MySQL requires fields (or in this case sets of fields) referenced by a foreign key must be indexed in the same order as referenced in keys.

Comment: @Uueerdo i modified the question. Thanks

Comment: @Akina i modified the question.

Comment: The graduate students can be filtered from the table student.

Comment: is it using the join command ? That is the only command that i know. But i dont think that will helpful in terms to creating the new table advisory .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the table `advisory` like this:

```
create table advisory (
  professor_id char(10),  
  student_id char(10),
  ISGraduate BOOLEAN default 1,
  foreign key (professor_id) references professor(net_id),
  foreign key (student_id, ISGraduate) references student(net_id, ISGraduate),
  primary key (professor_id, student_id)
);
```

and add a `unique` index in the table `student` for the columns `net_id` and `ISGraduate`:

```
create table student (
  net_id char(10), 
  first_name char(20),
  last_name char(20), 
  Major char(10), 
  ISGraduate BOOLEAN,
  unique(net_id, ISGraduate),
  primary key (net_id)
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nkmVZnbSL5dpFPpXCzAc9f/1).
Also make sure that the flag `foreign_keys` is ON by executing:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

and get the graduate students from this table with a join to `student`:

```
select s.* 
from student s inner join advisory a
on s.net_id = a.student_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there any alternative way that we can do the same thing using a foreign key constraint ?

Comment: There are 2 foreign keys in the table advisory.

Comment: This may be a very silly question because i am new to sql. Can we use ISGraduate also as a foreign key with some condition (ex: ISGraduate should be true) .?

Comment: thank you once again. As far as i understood,  in this advisory table we can add data of a student who is not a graduate student  without getting an error. But in reality this should only contain the data of graduate students.

Comment: Check my edited answer. The table advisory will contain only students who have ISGraduate = 1.